# I try to implement the iOS9 Universal Links

Tags: deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I want to know how to create apple-app-site-association file.

https://developerinsider.co/enable-universal-links-in-ios-app-and-setup-server-for-it/

The above links say to do it this way:

```
cat json.txt | openssl smime -sign -inkey example.com.key
    -signer example.com.pem
    -certfile intermediate.pem
    -noattr -nodetach
    -outform DER > apple-app-site-association
```

And I don't have the .pem and .key files and I don't know how to create it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this process detailed in a blog post from Alex Austin of Branch, here: https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios-9/

Here are the key bits:

**Section 2: Configuring your apple-app-site-association file**

Universal Links turn your website URL into an app link, so you need be running a web server in order to leverage them. To help with this process, use our Universal Links Validator to check if your apple-app-site-association file is configured properly.

**Pick a domain**

First, identify the domain that you’d like to use for your Universal Links. You can register a new one or use an existing. If registering a new one, we prefer to use a clean, non-spammy registrar like ghandi.net.

**Acquire SSL certification**

You need to acquire SSL certification files for the domain you’ll use to host the Universal Links. In order to do this, you’ll need to use a third party service to register your domain for SSL, and create the files you need. After looking around, we’ve chosen Digicert to handle branch.io and associated subdomains.

**Here are the steps to create your SSL certification:**

1. Visit https://www.digicert.com/easy-csr/openssl.htm and fill out the form at the top to generate an openSSL command. Keep this window open
2. Login to your remote server
3. Execute the openSSL command to generate a certificate signing request (.csr) and certification file (.cert)
4. Pay for your SSL certification at https://www.digicert.com/welcome/ssl-plus.htm
5. Wait for Digicert to approve and send you the final files
6. In the end, move yourdomain.com.cert, yourdomain.com.key and digicertintermediate.cert into the same directory on your remote server
   Create your apple-app-site-association JSON

There is a pretty standard structure of this JSON file, so you can basically just copy this version and edit it to fit your needs. I’ll breakdown where to get the correct values below.

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "R63EM248DP.io.branch.TestBed-Swift",
                "paths": [
                    "NOT /e/*",
                    "*",
                    "/"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The only fields you need to change are associated with: “R63EM248DP.io.branch.TestBed-Swift”. This is actually two values joined together with a period. Both values are found on developers.apple.com in the Identifiers -> App IDs section. Just click on the corresponding registered App ID.

In this example, connect the Prefix and the ID together with a period so that it looks like so: “R63EM248DP.io.branch.TestBed-Swift”.
Save this JSON file as apple-app-site-association-unsigned.

**Sign the JSON file with your SSL certificates**

Note: if you have certified your domain as HTTPS, you can skip this step and send the JSON in plaintext.

Upload the apple-app-site-association-unsigned file to your server into the same directory as the certification and key files from the previous steps. Using the command line, change directory into that folder and issue the following command:

```
cat apple-app-site-association-unsigned | openssl smime -sign -inkey yourdomain.com.key -signer yourdomain.com.cert -certfile digicertintermediate.cert -noattr -nodetach -outform DER > apple-app-site-association
```

This will generate the file apple-app-site-association

**Configure your file server**

Alright! So you have your signed apple-app-site-association file. Now you just need to configure your file server to host this for you. There are a few caveats:

- It must be sent with the header ‘application/pkcs7-mime’
- It must be sent from the endpoint youdomain.com/apple-app-site-association
- It must return a 200 http code.

We set up the one for all Branch integrated apps using our Node+Express link servers. Here’s the code we used in case that’s helpful:

```
var aasa = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/static/apple-app-site-association');app.get('/apple-app-site-association', function(req, res, next) {
     res.set('Content-Type', 'application/pkcs7-mime');
     res.status(200).send(aasa);
});
```

Again, you can avoid all the JSON hosting and SSL cert work and just use Branch links to host it for you. 
Happy Linking!